# Inbox that other users can write to

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to create a directory `/home/dotancohen/inbox/` in which other users on the system could write files to. I do not want them to have read or write access to `/home/dotancohen/`. I tried setting `/home/dotancohen/inbox/` to permissions 777 but as `/home/dotancohen/` is permission 700 they cannot access the inbox at all.

Is there any way to create this universally-writable inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your home directory to 0711 so that others can descend into it. Note that doing all this won't automatically give your user access to those files though. Consider a email-like system instead.

Comment: Thank you. I set `/home/dotancohen/` to 711 and `/home/dotancohen/inbox` to 777. Now my home directory is hidden but other users have full access to the contents of `~/inbox/`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create symlink in the directory available to all of the users pointing to /home/dotancohen/inbox/

```
ln -s /home/dotancohen/inbox/ /tmp/inbox
```

each user will be able to write to /tmp/inbox - it has been used for testing purposes your location should be different